# How do use HTML5 History Api on my Website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, history

Im a beginner and fairly new to programming (so please keep your answers simple as possible).

I just heard of HTML5 history API, This API lets you update browser address bar with JavaScript, so you can change the contents of the page according to the URL. (Which I have no idea how to do)

I'm currently using XAMPP as localhost, phpmyadmin as database, and using Notepadd++ as a file editor, viewing and testing my website on Google Chrome.

My questions is, how do I use this new HTML5 History API so that my 3 php files, work seamlessly when navigating between pages using purely PHP or javascript at most.
Best example I can give is exactly how soundcloud can play music seamlessly when navigating between pages.

I would like the same result and the same concept on my 'header', 'Vis1' and 'Vis' php files to work seamlessly when navigating between pages(these pages are listed).

Files I want to work seamlessly when navigating:

Directory: i-neo\htdocs\i-neo\inc..

```
   <?php include ( "./inc/header.inc.php" );?>
   <?php include("./inc/vis1.inc.php");?>
   <?php include("./inc/vis.inc.php");?>
```

These same 3 files are included all across the following php pages:

Directory: i-neo\htdocs\i-neo\

```
 'home.php, index.php,  msmyg.php, prof.php, nudg.php & frireq.php'
```

Coding below: vis1.inc.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <div id="vinfo">
        <meta name="description" content="blah">
        <title>blah</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
           <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="fileWrapper" class="file_wrapper">
                    <div id="info">
                    </div>
                        <label for="uploadedFile">
                        Drag & drop
                        </label>
                    <input type="file" id="uploadedFile">
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </head> 
</html>
```

Code for: vis.inc.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <footer>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
            <div id="v_wrapper">
               <canvas id='canvas' width="1950" height="800"><script            
                 type="text/javascript" src="js/hav.js"></script>             
                   </canvas>
                    </div>
             <div id="c2">
                <small>random info<a href="website name"      target="_blank">website name - Owner</a></small>
            </div>
      </footer>
</html>
```

Code for: header.inc.php

```
<?php 
   include ("./inc/connect.inc.php"); 
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
   $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
   }
   else {
   $user = "";
   }
   ?>
   <!doctype html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>i-neo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
   <body>
       <div class="ineoMenu">
        <div id="ineoWrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="./img/i-neo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="search_ineo">
                <form action="search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                    <input type="text" name="q" size="50"
 placeholder="Search" .../>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>

        <?php

        if (isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) 
        {
        echo '
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="home">Home</a>
                <a href="'.$use.'">Prof</a>

                <a href="set.php">Set</a>
                <a href="msmyg.php">Me</a>

                <a href="frireq.php.php">Fr</a>
                <a href="nudg.php">Nudg</a>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

            </div>
            ';
        } 
        else{

            echo'<div id="menu">
            <a href="index.php"/>S</a>
            <a href="index.php">L </a>
            </div>  
        ';
        }
        ?>

        <div id="wrapper">
</html>     
<footer>
    <div id="c1">           
        <?php echo "Hedi Bej &copy; i-neo 2015"; ?>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: "phpmyadmin as database" - phpmyadmin is not a database but a management tool for mysql.

Comment: Well you know what I meant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your PHP pages render a full webpage, so you're probably better off just using ordinary links between them.

You could remove all the parts that are the same on each, have the homepage render those and then when an internal link is pressed it could download the relevant section from your server and insert it into the page (using the History API to update the URL). You'd also want to have some way of having the server render the appropriate page in full after following a link to it, possibly by using some kind of server side routing.

To me, it doesn't look like you need to use the History API yet, your website will work fine with hyperlinks.

Comment: No, I want to use History API so that 3 php files I just stated, doesn't constantly refresh, when navigating across the website. Just like the soundcloud music player, I want it to work seamlessly while navigating across the website... That is my aim. Why is my question put on hold? I believe I'm asking for a simple & easy solution so that my 3 php files somehow work seamlessly while navigating. I believe that is narrow and simple enough. I want an answer that works, regardless how short/long it is, neither doesn't matter which way. Just give me 1 answer that works @ThiefMaster...

Comment: I described a way you could do it in my answer, maybe try that? Or look at how other people have done it, maybe read the soundcloud JavaScript.